# Odoo: How can i find a single user's all sessions in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

How can i find a single user's all sessions in Odoo v10, and need to logout all the sessions of that in one call via python. Like i know its stored in the local folder,But i don't how to differentiate session by user.Please do help here.

Answer (score 0):

Session management isn't used in odoo.

You can get some third party [APPS](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/tko_web_sessions_management/)

Comment: found a method to find out the sessions by using the werkzeug module